# How to install sasm on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 32-bit, configure

I am new user. I am trying to install SASM on ubuntu 18.04 i386 but but I can not find a file named configure in the link below, can you help me? https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Dman95/xUbuntu_18.04/?C=S;O=A

Answer (score 1):

There is a [third-party PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewide0/+archive/ubuntu/sasm), you can install SASM 3.11.1-1 from it using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wide0/sasm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sasm
```

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else lands here from Google search for a SASM PPA, the procedure to setup the SUSE repository is (as sudo):

```sh
wget -O- 'https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:Dman95/public_key' | apt-key add -
echo "deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Dman95/xUbuntu_$(lsb_release -sr) ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dman95-sasm.list
apt update
```

The PPA in the answer is abandoned (as of Oct/2021), and provides only Ubuntu 18.04 builds.